# AQ and Spring Integration - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 'defaultDestination' or 'defaultDestinationName' specified

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, dsl, spring-annotations

When trying to run an Spring Integration application on Weblogic and connect to AQ I am getting the following error:

```
 2016-11-08 18:07:53.677 ERROR 12864 --- [ask-scheduler-7] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 'defaultDestination' or 'defaultDestinationName' specified. Check configuration of JmsTe
mplate.
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.getRequiredDefaultDestinationName(JmsTemplate.java:216)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:738)
        at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsDestinationPollingSource.doReceiveJmsMessage(JmsDestinationPollingSource.java:141)
        at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsDestinationPollingSource.receive(JmsDestinationPollingSource.java:111)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:209)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class AQMessageProcessorApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DATAFLOW_ACDR = "urn:xeu:ec:fisheries:flux-bl:FLUX_ACDR_OtherReport:1:1";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AQMessageProcessorApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory aqConnectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private Destination aqAcdrQueue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AQMessageProcessorApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow aqAcdrInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                    .from(
                        Jms.inboundAdapter(this.aqConnectionFactory)
                                            .destination(aqQueue),
                        e -> e.poller( Pollers.fixedRate(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(100))
                     )
                     .enrich(e -> e
                            .requestPayload(Message::getPayload)
                            .shouldClonePayload(false)                                                                                                                                                  
                     )                   
                     .transform( message-> message )
                     .channel("entrypoint")
                     .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory aqConnectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory factory = null;
        JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
        try {
          factory = (ConnectionFactory) jndi.lookup("jms/QCF");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("NamingException for jms/QCF", e);
        }

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Destination aqWeblogicQueue() {
        Destination destination = null;
        JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
        try {
          destination = (Destination) jndi.lookup("jms/Q_TEST");    
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            logger.error("NamingException for jms/Q_TEST   ", e);
        }

        return destination;
    }
```

}

I have tried this code with WebLogic queues and it worked no problem.

What silly thing am I missing here?

Regards!

Comment: What is `aqQueue` variable in your code? Maybe it is `null`? That is the reason of that error.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I assumed once I have created the queue in Weblogic then it won't be null, but as there was a connection error between AQ and WebLogic a JNDI lookup returned null.

Comment: ??? Does it mean that you have fixed your issue? Maybe we can close this question as invalid? Just because you don't mention there that you have some connection problems...